# Add Alamofire as dependency through Swift 3 package manager

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift3, vapor

**Swift 3** introduced **package manager**, with which I can add dependencies to my project.

For example, in my **Package.swift** , I can declare my dependency by:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "my-project",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 16),
    ]
)
```

Now, I need to add [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to my project, how can I get it through Swift 3 package manager?

Comment: use cocoapods to add Alamofire in your app .It will help you also to resolve dependencies ..

Comment: @EricAya, your answer sounds like something I need. So, I need to clone the Alaofire repo & check out to "Swift 3" branch on my local machine, then, how to point to a local reposiotry of branch "Swift 3" in my Package.swift file? Could you please provide more detail and make an answer?

Comment: Thanks, Eric, in the mean time, I will be also trying it soon

Comment: Yep, alright, thank you anyhow :)

Comment: related https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1544

Answer (score 4):

You can't use Alamofire yet because they haven't released Swift 3 support.

Once they've released this, I'm sure they will make it obvious on their GitHub readme how to import it.

Luckily Vapor comes with a great HTTP and even WebSockets client. Read more about the HTTP client in the documentation: https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/client.html

Comment: I highly recommend using Vapor's built-in HTTP Client, pretty well put together and well designed for the backend.

Answer (score 2):

Well, today you just have to add the following line in your Package.swift file:
`.Package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", majorVersion: 4)`
Really easy :)